# FadeIn FadeOut error - "$ not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning the basics of Jquery's fadeIn and fadeOut function.
I thought It was going to be a success however it doesnt work. The console says I haven't defined $. How do I define this? Any clues at all?
My JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/57wyxe02/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="example"></div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.#example{
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:50%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:black;
    display:none;
}
#box{
    margin:auto;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:black;    
}
```

Jquery:

```
$("#box").click(function(){
    $("#example").fadeIn("normal");
});

$("#box").click(function(){
    $("#example").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: You have to choose a jquery version in the left uppercorner of jsfiddle.

Comment: Kim is correct. See this update I just added. The code doesn't work as I expect you want it to, but it fixes the error http://jsfiddle.net/57wyxe02/2/

Comment: Great, my code is perfectly fine but the fadein/out doesn't work?

Comment: @ClarkeCribb jQuery isn't part of the JavaScript language, it's just a library of helpful functions written in JavaScript. As such, you first have to load it on every page you want to use it on, same as you would any other library of code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? (you have some errors in you JSFiddle and you must call for jQuery on the left menu (Frameworks))

**CSS**

```
#example{
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:50%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:black;
    display:none;
}
#box{
    margin:auto;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:black;    
}
```

**jQuery**

```
    $("#box").click(function(){
    $("#example").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/57wyxe02/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

$ in your code means you are using a jquery function.

“$ not defined” usually means jquery is not loaded, please make sure you load jquery

Answer (score 0):

You have one dot (.) before #example in CSS - just delete it.

Do not put two event handler listening for the same event on one DOM-element, because you will never know which one is called first.

Better do something like this:

```
var active = false;
$("#box").click(function () {
    if (active) {
        $("#example").fadeOut("slow");
        active = false;
    } else {
        $("#example").fadeIn("normal");
        active = true;
    }
});
```

Try it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/57wyxe02/9/

Hope that helps!